# I have a focus problem in C# GUI with tabs

Tags: c#, tabs, tabcontrol

I have a focus problem in C# GUI with tabs.
I start a process based on an event with the users focus on a tab, and then run the process.
The process repaints the the entire GUI -- and I'd like to put the user back on the initial tab.

Is there a way I can save the tab focus position when the event is triggered?

Cheers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just save the SelectedTab (or SelectedIndex) property of your TabControl and then set it again afterwards.

Comment: int TabLocation = tabControl1.SelectedIndex;
---run some stuff
tabControl1.SelectedIndex = TabLocation;

Unfortunately, this looks "jerky" in the repaint. 

Is there anyway to set the tab selected when the items are initially  made?

Comment: Attach some code to the LostFocus event. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.lostfocus.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Store the tab focus position value when they first arrive on that tab. If the event fires afterward, you'll have already saved the prior position and can use that value to restore the original focus.